# Track S3 File upload progress from GraphQL Mutation

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify

Im currently trying to upload a file with help of the [documentation](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/android/storage#usage-with-graphql-apis-complex-objects) (Android). For that I am using the complex object way, so I have a dynamoDB entry and the S3 File upload at once. So I am **not** using `TransferUtility` .For now it is working fine, but there is something I couldn't find out from the docs.
***How can I track the progress of my file upload ?***


The options for the `TransferUtility` are written down but not for the graphql way. The only thing Im getting back now is the callback/response from the dynamodb mutation request.

Answer (score 1):

Closest thing you might find in GraphQLCall.Callback is the `onStatusEvent` callback, in which you get a `StatusEvent` enum:

```js
enum StatusEvent {
  SCHEDULED,
  FETCH_CACHE,
  FETCH_NETWORK,
  COMPLETED
}
```

Found this in the [AWS Labs Git repo](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-mobile-appsync-sdk-android/blob/master/aws-android-sdk-appsync/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/mobileconnectors/appsync/AppSyncCallback.java).